# BookshelfJS collection.length and collection.models.length different count

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I do

```
User.query(function(qb) { qb.leftJoin(bookshelf.knex.raw('dialogs on (users.id = dialogs.p1_id or users.id = dialogs.p2_id or dialogs.id is null)')).whereRaw('users.language = ? and (dialogs.`status` <> ? or dialogs.`status` <> ? or dialogs.id is null) and users.id <> ?', [languageFound, 'opened', 'running', msg.from.id]).limit(config.get('minDialogs')) }).fetchAll()
.then(function(users) {
console.info('Free users: ' + users.length);
array2 = users.models.map(function(user) { ...
```

What is strange for me, the result contains this:
    users.length = A
    users.models.length = B
where B > A

May be I misunderstand smth about bookshelfjs?
How can I pass through the users fetched models?
According to the DB users.length but how to get them all and what is users.models array??? There are many duplicate items.

Comment: Are these `length` attributes documented somewhere? I've found no reference to them.

Comment: No, not. But I have found it while inspecting the object.

Comment: The Bookshelf endorsed way of working on collections are the [lodash methods](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-subsection-lodash-methods). You should perhaps give them a try instead of those undocumented features.